# angularjs how to get attribute value

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and here is a dumb question

View:

```
 <select id="Select1" ng-model="tld" class="form-control ">
                        <option value="net" data-id="2">.net</option>
                        <option value="vn" data-id="3">.vn</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-test" ng-click="checkDomain(newDomain,tld)" value="CheckDomain">
```

On controller:

I can get the tld value(net or vn) fine, but how can i get the data-id associated with the clicked item in Select ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I have an array bound to the select box, seems like a better approach. But, you could try to have a json object as the value argument, like `<option value="{ text: 'net', id: 2 }">.net</option>`.